# Big values in C++

Tags: c++

I'm doing a fibonacci and I want to save all the numbers in a .txt, i have done the code but when the cicles gets big values the program express it as an exponential, and then gets bigger as .INF.
How I can save the entry number?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()  {

    ofstream File;
    File.open("fibo.txt");

    double val0 = 0, val1 = 1, i = 0, n, out;
    cout << "Enter n of Fibonacci(n): ";
    cin >> n;

    while (i < n)   {
        if (n == 0) {
            File << i << "- " << 0 << endl;
            i++;
        }
        else    {
            out = val0 + val1;
            val0 = val1;
            val1 = out;
            i++;
            File << i << "- " << val0 << endl;
            }
        }
        File.close();
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Search for multi-precision libraries.

Comment: Don't use floating-point types for such kind of problems due to precision issues.

Comment: `double` is only 64 bits wide

Comment: @AlexYan It is not that much related to the size of `double`, but to its precision. (And the size of `double` is not guaranteed to be 64 BTW.)

Comment: You can use `unsigned long long` (or `size_t` in x64 platform) instead of the `double`. in windows you also have __int64.

Comment: @SHR or just use the standard `uint64_t`. Also, `__int64 != size_t == unsigned long long`.

Comment: @AlexD That's what I'm saying... 64 bits isn't very precise if you have to spread it out over a dozen or so digits worth of real numbers. The farther you are from 0, the wider the gaps in between numbers, and the more imprecise you are. The problem is that you need more bytes as your result blows up, so you should use the numeric types provided in one of those arbitrary precision libraries like Boost, or GNU MP. koopad you shouldn't use any native numeric types if you want to be precise

Comment: @CoffeeandCode I think `uint64_t` is c++11, I wasn't sure about the compiler and version, just suggested some bigger types he can use instead of the `double`.

Comment: @SHR well, I mean, it *is* 2015 and C++14 is the current standard. I just take C++11 for granted these days.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [boost::multiprecision](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/libs/multiprecision/doc/html/index.html), it's very intuitive and easy to use. Your code can be modified by changing (only) a couple of lines:

```
#include <boost/multiprecision/cpp_int.hpp> // need this

#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;
using namespace boost::multiprecision;

int main()
{

    ofstream File;
    File.open("fibo.txt");

    cpp_int val0 = 0, val1 = 1, out; // arbitrary precision integers
    int i = 0, n;
    cout << "Enter n of Fibonacci(n): ";
    cin >> n;

    while (i < n)   {
        if (n == 0) {
            File << i << "- " << 0 << endl;
            i++;
        }
        else    {
            out = val0 + val1;
            val0 = val1;
            val1 = out;
            i++;
            File << i << "- " << val0 << endl;
        }
    }
    File.close();
    return 0;
}
```